# Changing button text and function onClick not Working on Ipad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one button on my current web application.

- When you open the page, it says **Compare** and when clicked it compares 2 products side by side.
- After you click compare, the button changes to **Back** and then when clicked refreshes the page.

The problem is that this only works on desktop. When I change it via chrome devtools to iPhone or iPad it stays as compare even when clicked and doesn't change.

**I have tried:** creating two separate buttons that are displayed/hidden when appropriate and using a single button and changing it's text but either way, it works on desktop but not iPhone/iPad view.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
<div class="list-group">   
  <button type="button" class='btn goCompare' id="goCompare" data-show="compareBack" style="width: 100%;">Compare</button>
</div>
```

```
<body>
  <div>
      <button id="compare">Compare</button>
      <button id="back" style="display: none;">Back</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('compare').onclick=function(){
      document.getElementById('compare').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('back').style.display = "block";
    }
    document.getElementById('back').onclick=function(){
      document.getElementById('compare').style.display = "none";
      refreshPage();
    }
    function refreshPage() {
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Add and remove a class

Comment: I agree with @MaxBaldwin you should use a class to see whether it is toggled correctly. I tried running your code in a pen and it seemed to function correctly. Also, unrelated, but look to use querySelectors, might make your code a bit easier to read. Also you can extract your goCompare dom node selector to a variable so you dont have to call it twice.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to have two buttons instead of one (back and compare), and hide one of them depending on your needs. You can play with the display property of the element as below:

```
 document.getElementById("goCompare").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not make a second button. You should simply use a classes to indicate what state your button is in.

I added a class to your button that indicates that this is not the refresh state of the button.

```
 <button type="button" class='noRefresh btn goCompare' id="goCompare" data-show="compareBack" style="width: 100%;">Compare</button>
```

And here is a function that uses that class to change the state of the button

```
<script>
function onClick() {
    var classes = this.classList;
  if (classes.contains('isRefresh')) {
    // refresh
    console.log('refresh');
    this.classList.add('noRefresh');
    this.classList.remove('isRefresh');
   } else if (classes.contains('noRefresh')) {
    // don't refresh
    console.log('no refresh');
    this.classList.add('isRefresh');
    this.classList.remove('noRefresh');
   }
}

document.getElementById('goCompare').onclick=onClick
</script>
```

The keyword `this` is a reference to the button. Not the function. You can open your javascript console and see the console logs in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin2328/9htgr7zp/7/).

Comment: @bicycle4431 have a look at the jsFiddle I added. As I mentioned I had to add a class to your HTML. The code above does work so check your implementation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `location.reload()` which is known to have bugs on Mac devices. Try changing it to `location.reload(true)`
Check out a working Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/BayjmMV?editors=1010)

Comment: That still didnt fix the issue unfortunately, but even if that was the problem, not even the text in the button changes...

Comment: I ran the code on my machine, changed the device to iPhone X and then iPad Pro and it worked, can you add more code that you think might be relevant to the problem?

Comment: At this point I would just follow the answer posted by @SaWo. Seeing the problem is not necessarily with `location.reload()` as it won't even change the text inside the button I would just create 2 separate buttons and change the styling via Javascript to show/hide buttons accordingly (don't forget to include the `goCompare` class in both of your buttons so that you won't have to re-write any php/js code that rely on that class

Comment: I used ``` to indent your code better so that it's easier to view on SO (I usually use ``` instead of 4 tabs when writing code on SO) other than that yes the code is what @SaWo suggested, there is no strict "best way" of approaching this problem, using `location.reload()` would have been less of a pain but as we saw it's a bit troublesome on IOS, I would call this the right solution for your particular case, don't forget to mark @SaWo's answer as being the correct one!